# Interior 30s wall construction

Tags: plaster, uk

can anyone identify the materials in this wall? It's an interior wall in a 1930s UK house. Obviously ... bricks, and the outside is some kind of lime plaster I think. What is the black material?

[image: wall]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Brown" or undercoat plaster - *i.e.* not finish plaster (what shows on the outside.)

Comment: Ah thanks! Found [this page](https://www.oldtownhome.com/2013/10/23/Plaster-Repair-Part-2-Laying-a-New-Brown-Coat/) with some good info about. Also mentions the gritty plaster not being finished when wallpapered which was the case here.